# How does Matlab store this large of a number with only 64 bits?

Tags: matlab, floating-point, precision

The largest number in double precision (that is, 64 bit) floating point arithmetic is
`1.111...110 x 2^(512)` (where there are 51 `1`'s after the radix point). This number is less than `2 x 2^(512) == 2^(513) == 8^(171) < 10^(171)`. Therefore, when I assign `x = 10^(171)`, I expect that `x` will be stored as `Inf`. However, this is not the case. Calling `x` in the interactive console displays `1.0000e+171`. The only explanation I could think of is that Matlab uses more than 64 bits to store `x`. But a quick check of `whos x` reveals that `x` is stored in 8 bytes.

In fact, the largest power of `10` which will not be stored as `Inf` is `10^308`.

Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I made a simple mistake here. In 64 bit arithmetic, 11 bits are used to encode the exponent. Therefore we have `2^(11) = 2048` possible exponents, and so they range from `-1023` to `1024`, not from `-511` to `512` like I thought. Therefore the largest number in 64 bit arithmetic is  $1.111...110 x 2^(1024)$, which is in fact (with the exponent having 3 significant digits) `10^(308.6)`, corroborating my experimental results.

Comment: Matlab helps you with some of these explorations. For example, see `realmax`, `reammin` and `eps`.

Comment: @Pursuit Interesting, thanks! Do you know of any package or collection of commands which is designed for for understanding floating point arithmetic?

Comment: The exponent values range from −1022 to +1023. The exponent field values of 0 and 2047 are reserved for subnormals and NaNs and infinities. The largest representable finite number is (2−2^−53)•2^1023 = 2^1024−2^971, about 10^308.25.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for your clarification. I was under the impression `Inf` was represented only by `01111...11` (63 `1`'s). Are you saying that any positive mantissa, when combined with an exponent field value of `2047`, represents `Inf`? That seems like a waste of `2^(52)-1` perfectly good numbers.

Comment: @user56202: The preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point representation is “significand,” not “mantissa.” “Mantissa” is an old word for the fraction portion of a logarithm. Significands are linear. Mantissas are logarithmic. The low bits of an IEEE-754 binary floating-point encoding are the trailing significand field. This is not a significand until it is combined with a leading bit, which is encoded by way of the exponent field. When the exponent field is all 1s, there is no significand: If the trailing significand field is all 0s, the encoding represents an infinity…

Comment: … (+∞ or −∞ according to the sign bit.) If the trailing significand field is not all 0s, the encoding represents a Not a Number (NaN). If the first bit of the field is 1, it should be a quiet NaN (this is recommended but not required by the IEEE-754 standard). Otherwise, it is a signaling NaN. The other bits of the field may be used for diagnostic/debug/special purposes, as desired by the implementation and the user.